# Issue when uploading video on Vimeo (through my iOS app)

Tags: ios, vimeo

I am facing issue when uploading video from iOS application on behalf of other users.

Steps are below:

1. In Vimeo, I logged in with my company account and created Vimeo app.
2. After that I sent a request to Vimeo for **Upload** scope.
3. Then my app approved for Upload scope, and I have client_id, secret_id, redirect_ui, etc..

MyApps: https://developer.vimeo.com/apps

Then, I was following OAuth flow, for that I am opening following url in mobile app browser:

https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize?**response_type**=code&**client_id**=XXX&**scope**=upload&**redirect_uri**=XXX&state=XXX

but I am getting following error:

> An error has occurred. You won't be able to connect to Vimeo until it
>   is fixed by the developer.
>       Dear app owner, we are unable to generate access tokens using one or more of the scopes you provided.

If anyone faced this issue, let me know the solution. Also let me know if any other detail needed to rectify this issue.

Comment: have you tried to set response_type as "token" instead of "code"? Because as per document you may have to use token if you are plaining to use token in Browser. Please refer https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#authorization-grant-workflow.

Comment: token also doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication) the private scope is:

> Required for any scope other than public.

It also says the following regarding the response_type parameter:

> The OAuth response type. Use authorization_code for the authorization code grant.

Comment: I used this but not worked: https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=dc1b97abdc062f0c357968657ef33d3f3b012f1d&scope=private%20upload&redirect_uri=http://www.google.com&state=narendar

Comment: It's a space seperated list, correct. But it's also a URL, use %20 instead of space so scope=private%20upload

Comment: Hi Dennis, I am using scope=private%20upload, didn't you notice that in the URL I mentioned above? Please check it and let me know what's wrong here.